# Wrapping cstrings (const char*) to be able to store them into a STL container

Tags: c++, boost, stl, type-traits

I need to store some various types of variables into an stl container (std::map in this case). Although, when it occurs that this variable is a string, I cannot afford to use std::string because memory usage is critical.

Hence, I need to find a way to store all my strings as cstrings (const char*) into that map. So I tryed to code make some kind of class to hold the value:

```
template<class T>
class ValueHolder {
private:
    T value;
public:
    ValueHolder(const T &argValue) :
        value(argValue) {
    }
    const T& getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    ~ValueHolder() {}
};

template<>
class ValueHolder<const char*> {
private:
    char* value;

public:
    ValueHolder(const char* argValue) {
        value = strdup(argValue);
        std::cout << "constructing ValueHolder(const char*) " << value << std::endl;
    }
    ValueHolder(const ValueHolder<const char*> &argExtension) {
        value = strdup(argExtension.value);
    }
    const char* getValue() const {
        std::cout << "returning ValueHolder(const char*) " << value << std::endl;
        return value;
    }
    ~ValueHolder() {
        if(value != NULL)
            free(value);
    }
};
```

Then, I declared the std::map

```
std::map<ValueType::Type, boost::any> extensions_;
```

And here are the functions which allow to set and retrieve it (using boost::any):

```
template<class Type>
Type getExtension(const ValueType::Type &argValueType) const {
    std::map<ValueType::Type, boost::any>::const_iterator it = extensions_.find(argValueType);
    if(it != extensions_.end()) {
        switch(argValueType) {
        case ValueType::VAL_INT:
            if(boost::is_same<EnumFooType::Type, Type>::value) {
                return (boost::any_cast<ValueHolder<Type> >((*it).second)).getValue();
            } else {
                std::cout << "Wrong type for this value" << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        case ValueType::VAL_STR_1:
        case ValueType::VAL_STR_2:
            if(boost::is_same<const char *, typename boost::decay<Type>::type>::value) {
                return (boost::any_cast<ValueHolder<Type> >((*it).second)).getValue();
            } else {
                std::cout << "Wrong type value for this Holder" << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unhandled type of value, skipping..." << std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    throw ValueNotFoundException("Could not find a value for this subscriber extension");
}

template<class T>
void setExtension(const ValueType::Type &argExtensionType , T argExtensionValue) {
    boost::any any_value;
    switch(argExtensionType) {
    case ValueType::VAL_INT:
        if(boost::is_same<EnumFooType::Type, T>::value) {
            any_value = ValueHolder<T>(argExtensionValue);
            extensions_[argExtensionType] = any_value;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Wrong type value for Billing subscriber extension" << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    case ValueType::VAL_STR_1:
    case ValueType::VAL_STR_2:
        if(boost::is_same<const char *, typename boost::decay<T>::type>::value) {
            any_value = ValueHolder<T>(argExtensionValue);
            extensions_[argExtensionType] = any_value;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Wrong type for this value, it should be a cstring!" << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unhandled value type, skipping..." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the value returned when the specified type is a cstring (const char*) is not right, here is my test program output:

> constructing ValueHolder(const char*) FR
>
> Good enum value :)
>
> returning ValueHolder(const char*) FR
>
> !!!ERROR!!! Value is �� instead of FR

I'll provide an online test program later if needed, but both liveworkspace and coliru are down at the moment.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here is a test program: http://codepad.org/zbLQDAiS

**EDIT2:** Here the program I used to measure the memory usage with const char* and std::string: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3b3c4d7ce1d8d1400e3f6e45f75040dc-9294698a18feab30c803b17d837ba467

I simply made it a daemon and took a look at the process memory usage using top.

**EDIT3:** Here is an interesting article which shows about the same result: http://jovislab.com/blog/?p=76

Comment: There is also ideone: http://ideone.com/ ... actually this previous thread has a whole bunch of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Comment: Yes, but it does not work with boost. Edit: codepad does in fact! I'm adding that test program any minute! Thanks!

Comment: Why is `std::string` worse than `char*`? `std::string` should allocate the same amount of memory as you allocate with `char*` but wrap an object around it. The memory consumption should be either the same, or very similar. IT sounds to me like you're putting a lot of effort to fix a non-issue.

Comment: Well, in practice, with a class with 3 strings instanciated 100M times takes about 25Go RAM, while a class with 3 cstrings instanciated as many times only takes 10Go RAM... Basicly, I cannot afford allocating 25Go RAM

Comment: Good point (and kudos for measuring). Is this with any optimizations? with debug symbols?) The discrepancy is quite big.

Comment: I edited my last post, it was not 70 but 25Go, but it's still far too much memory consuming... It's built with O3 and -g...

Comment: I've just tryed, it gives the same result without debug options

Comment: Show your test code. This amount of memory you have measured is way too high.

Comment: Ugh stop doing this and instead use references/pointers to std::string where you want to intern strings.

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot afford" `std::string`? What do you think it is doing that is so expensive? _[edit: have read your comment to Syffys. OMG. What? You need to find a **different** storage mechanism as a map of strings coming to 25GB (wtf is a Go?) is not fit for purpose. The solution is not to make memory management a living hell, but to fix your inappropriate data model.]_

Comment: Go is the french version of GB, my bad. I'll add a sample to show how I measured that, it's not really complicated (It does not use a map)....

Comment: OK so you want fixed-size character arrays, equal in size to mere two pointers. Not full-featured arbitrary-sized dynamically-allocated strings. That's what you have measured at any rate. You should have started with that. If this is the case, you do NOT want to store `const char*`. You don't want to muck with pointers at all. Make a `struct mystring { char[16] value; }` and be done with it. Store `struct mystring` (not a pointer) in your map. If you think you need features of something that is not `char[16]`, measure the performance something that is not `char[16]` first.

Comment: I don't want fixed-size character arrays... What shows the measures is that small size std::string have a big overhead. Big, but fixed, which means that it tends to be negligible at some point if the string is big enough. That said, it's clear that allocating a fixed size array would be a deep waste of resources in my case, and my strings won't be big enough, so this overhead is not worth it. Also, I don't see what it would prove to measure memory consumption of a `char[17]` for instance, a char size is 1B, there's nothing else to know... Memory usage would be linear.

Comment: If you don't want fixed-size character arrays, why measure their performance, and draw far-reaching conclusions out of the experiment? If you didn't want to measure them, why *have* you measured them?

Comment: The fact is that I had measured this for an other problem, and I knew this would cause me an other issue on this case... While you're right, that dynamically allocated char array is not going to take the same memory than a fixed size char array, it's still a lot less than std::string. Anyways, I'm thinking about using boost::flyweight in this case because I'm going to end with a lot more references than different actual values. However, my question about why I can't manage to get the excepted string while using a char* still stands...